# 'Internal space embedding need ...' error when attemping to use spaCy text_categorizer

Tags: python, spacy

Hello sirs and madams,

I very much need your help to understand this error:

```
Exception has occurred: NotImplementedError
internal spacy embeddings need to be derived from md/lg spacy models not from sm/trf models.
File "/Users/Rune/Sites/smartez-backend/analytics/pipeline.py", line 517, in categorize_new
result = nlp("new_sentence")._.cats
File "/Users/Rune/Sites/smartez-backend/components/feed.py", line 471, in p_get_posts
category = pipeline.categorize_new(post)
File "/Users/Rune/Sites/smartez-backend/queue_.py", line 22, in set_run
categories, lang = feed_source.p_get_posts()
File "/Users/Rune/Sites/smartez-backend/queue_.py", line 44, in <module>
set_run(wait)
```

I get the error when I attempt debugging the code in vs code on mac/ox:

```
data = self.load_data(self.language['language'])
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
nlp.add_pipe("text_categorizer",
         config={
             "data": data,
             "model": "spacy"
            }
)
```

The code is in the file: 'smartez-backend/analytics/pipeline.py'

When I try similar code in the file: 'smartez-backend/test.py' it works like a charm.

I simply cannot comprehend why this error occurs, and any help will payed back with much gratitude.

Best,
Rune

Comment: It follows the example in the documentation: https://spacy.io/universe/project/classyclassification

Comment: Not sure what `smartez` is but it must be using `spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")` (notice the `sm`) or something?

Comment: No, I use the medium language model: 'en_core_web_md' as it says in the code (and documentation)